# How do I add elements after a ZStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I try to place an element after a ZStack, the element ends up sitting on top of some of the ZStack elements. Is there a way to make it so the elements render under the ZStack, or do I need to make another view? Code below with rendered screen as well.

[image: rendered image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.init(hex: "050607"), Color.init(hex: "585A5E")]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .top)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("Tesla")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: "C9CBCD"))
                Text("Cybertruck")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                VStack {
                    ZStack{
                        HStack {
                            Text("297")
                                .font(.system(size:150))
                                .fontWeight(.thin)
                            Text("km")
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .fontWeight(.thin)
                                .offset(y: -45)
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        Image("cybertruck")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 500)
                            .offset(x: 50, y: 110)

                    }
                    Text("A/C is turned on")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("Tap to open the car")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we get more code? The code above doesn't compile because you can only have 1 view in your body but you have a ZStack, and 2 text. Is there another ZStack wrapping everything that you didn't include in your code snippet?

Comment: @sfung3 I've added more code for clarification. Now you can use the entire Content View. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your use of `offset`. Put borders around your views and you'll be able to see what's going on. `offset` causes elements to render outside their frames. The ZStack will be the size required to hold the original placement, and the VStack elements will be placed under that. Then the offsets will move the elements, causing things to overlap.

If you detail the exact layout you want, we may be able to help you redesign without offsets.

Your Text probably wants a baselineOffset or alignmentGuide rather than offset. Your Image also probably wants an alignmentGuide to make it line up with whatever you're trying to match it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `zIndex` for your elements in the view, and then arrange them as you need